# Melt a dataframe using a list column

Tags: r

From a dataframe which has a column list:

```
`id text stock 
 1 text1 c("Google", "Yahoo")  
2  test  Yahoo`
data <- data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("text1", "test"), stock = c("c("Google", "Yahoo")", "Yahoo")
```

How could it be possible to melt this dataframe in this format
id text stock

```
`1  text1 Google 
1  text1 Yahoo 
2  test  Yahoo`
```

Comment: Please provide a real example of your data/code, not just pseudo code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Domin D, your data isn't reproducible. It has an unexpected symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple `unnest()` from `tidyr`:

```r
library(tidyr)
dat <- tribble(~id, ~text, ~stock, 
               1, "text1", c("Google", "Yahoo"),
               2,  "test", "Yahoo")
unnest(dat, cols = stock)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>      id text  stock 
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1     1 text1 Google
#> 2     1 text1 Yahoo 
#> 3     2 test  Yahoo
```

PS, before posting, please check that your code actually creates a minimal sample dataset. Your line with `data.frame` is bugged.